# How to pass string inside src attribute of image tag <img src=""> using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a image tag which is :

```
<img id="imageUpload" alt="your image" style="display: none;">
```

I have a base64 code(it is working) of which i have added in string:

```
var imgName="data:image/png;base64,"+base64codes+"";
console.log(imgName);
```

How to pass the string value inside the src attribute of image using jquery/javascript?

I tried to pass the `imgName` inside `attr` using jquery but it is not working.

```
$('#imageUpload').attr('src',imgName);
```

my console for imgName is :

[image]

Comment: ' but it is not working' -- This is a pretty vague description. Can you elaborate on what is happening exactly?

Comment: What does your `console.log(imgName);` pring in console?

Comment: the string which i initilaized imgName  is not getting passes into <img src=""> as the value of imgName must appear in src attribute

Comment: edited the post @DavidR

Comment: @AshwinKarki That does not help alot, we can not verify that string from that image... Paste it instead.

Comment: Because your code "style='display:none'",you can check html in browser,see if src attribute has been added to image tag.

Comment: To confirm: the issue with "it is not working" is just because your image was still hidden???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Maybe you just have to remove the style 'display: none'

```
$('#imageUpload').attr('style', '');
```